# Magento: 404 error when i am trying to edit/create an order from admin section

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am struggling with a problem. What the problem is, I am not able to edit the order or create a new order from admin section.

When i tries to edit an order it is giving 404 error. Magento is not able to go to relevant controller.

If anybody have any solution for this, please help me.

thanks in advance,
pradeep

Answer (score 1):

What URL is your browser at when you get the error?

Before going further, try refreshing the cache and logging out and logging back in. I find that those often solve URL problems.